# GCC attribute warning with trailing return type when return type is a class

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

GCC 4.9.1 does not appear to like function declarations with a trailing return type with attributes when the return type is a class.

Consider this following simplistic testcase:

```cpp
struct bar
{
    int a;
    bar (int a) : a(a) {}
};

auto foo() -> bar __attribute__((unused));
auto foo() -> bar { return bar(5); }

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

GCC prints a bizarre warning in regards to the attribute:

```
argh.cpp:2:41: warning: ignoring attributes applied to class type ‘bar’ outside of definition [-Wattributes]
 auto foo() -> bar __attribute__((unused)) {return bar(5);}
```

Merging the declaration with the definition does not silence the warning, and this only happens when the return type is a class-type, it works fine with `int`. What is going on? Why does GCC not like this particular function declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in the attribute parser used by GCC. The GCC manual warns about potential problems with the attribute grammar :

6.31 Attribute Syntax

> Because of infelicities in the grammar for attributes, some forms
>   described here may not be successfully parsed in all cases.
>
> There are some problems with the semantics of attributes in C++. [...] For example, there are no manglings for attributes, although they may affect code generation, so problems may arise when attributed types are used in conjunction with templates or overloading.

A warning about attribute parsing after a trailing return type would be helpful too.

> An attribute specifier list may appear immediately before a declarator
>   [...]

You should try to place the attribute before the prototype :

```
 __attribute__((unused)) 
auto foo() -> bar ;
auto foo() -> bar { return bar(5); }
```

and it should be OK without any warning.

> An attribute specifier list may appear immediately before the comma, =
>   or semicolon terminating the declaration of an identifier other than a
>   function definition. Such attribute specifiers apply to the declared
>   object or function.

I guess that positioning the function attribute after the function **declaration** is OK unless there is a trailing return type.

Answer (score 1):

Clang (as usual) gives a better warning in this case:

```
example.cpp:7:34: warning: 'unused' attribute ignored when parsing type
      [-Wignored-attributes]
auto foo() -> bar __attribute__((unused));
                                 ^~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Just like GCC is telling you, that attribute is meaningless in the context you're using it. It's conceptually the same as doing something like:

```
const int f(void) { return 5 };
```

The `const` there just doesn't *mean* anything.

Answer (score 1):

The [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax) implies that the syntax is not supported at the moment.

> An attribute specifier list may, in future, be permitted to appear
>   after the declarator in a function definition (before any old-style
>   parameter declarations or the function body).

N3337 describes the grammar of a function definition in [dcl.fct.def]:

> *function-definition:*
>
> *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *decl-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *declarator virt-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *function-body*
>
> ...
>
> `2` The *declarator* in a *function-definition* shall have the form
>
> > `D1` ( *parameter-declaration-clause* )
> >     *cv-qualifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub>
> >
> > *ref-qualifier*<sub>opt</sub>
> >     *exception-specification*<sub>opt</sub> *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *trailing-return-type*<sub>opt</sub>

As you can see the *trailing-return-type* is part of the *declarator* which appears before the *function-body*. Try changing your code to this:

```
auto __attribute__((unused)) foo() -> bar;
```